# Integrate Cloudinary updates with my application

Tags: amazon-s3, cloudinary

How to notify my application with step by step on new Cloudinary files created or existing Cloudinary files modified? How to integrate with Amazon SQS?

I have referred to the link, https://cloudinary.com/documentation/integrating_cloudinary_with_other_platforms but it does not give in step by step detail.

Answer (score 1):

You can set webhook notifications in Cloudinary to alert for various events. If you want a trigger to receive all notifications, set `event_type` to `all`, [see docs here](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/notifications#managing_webhook_notifications_programmatically). Cloudinary doesn't have official docs for integration with Amazon SQS, but I [found this](https://www.appypie.com/connect/apps/amazon-sqs/integrations/cloudinary) that might help.